# visual studio 2008 "reportviewer.exe has changed since it was initially published"

Tags: visual-studio

So I guess they decided to update visual studio report viewer, without feeling it necessary to update the file that gets downloaded?
I installed VS.Net 2008 SP1 and republished, but that didn't fix it...
Can I fix what file gets downloaded, or do I need to find the file, and set up a local repository?

Edit: Sorry, this is for a Click Once deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the location where VS finds the prerequisites.  Instead of choosing "component vendor's web site", you can choose "same location as my application" and it will publish the new Report Viewer with it.  See here:
http://joewirtley.blogspot.com/2007/07/clickonce-and-reportviewer.html